# asp.net checkbox list not registering as selected

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm trying to find the indexes of the checkbox list where the checkboxes are selected.

I've tried the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attendance_CBL.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (attendance_CBL.Items[i].Selected)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

But for some reason 'attendance_CBL.Items[i].Selected' always returns false; even if they are selected at that index.

Here's the page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database = DBConnection.getInstance();
        connection = database.getConnection();
        firstNames = new List<String>();
        lastNames = new List<String>();
        studentID = new List<String>();
        displayStudents();


    }
```

And here is where I am populating the checkbox list:

```
private void displayStudents()
    {

        attendance_CBL.Items.Clear();

        string id = "SELECT StudentID FROM StudentsTutorialSessions WHERE TutorialName = '" + Session["subcourse"].ToString() + "'";
        string firstName = "";
        string lastName = "";
        string studentID = "";



        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(id, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string name = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, StudentID FROM TemporaryStudents WHERE StudentID = '" + reader["StudentID"].ToString() + "' UNION SELECT FirstName, LastName, StudentID FROM FullyRegisteredStudents WHERE StudentID = '" + reader["StudentID"].ToString() + "'";
                OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand(name, connection);
                OleDbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    firstName = reader2["FirstName"].ToString();
                    lastName = reader2["LastName"].ToString();
                    studentID = reader2["StudentID"].ToString();
                    attendance_CBL.Items.Add(firstName + " " + lastName + " - " + studentID);
                    firstNames.Add(firstName);
                    lastNames.Add(lastName);
                    this.studentID.Add(studentID);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you fill the CheckBoxList? Are the items declared in markup?

Comment: On page load I select the names from the database and while reader.Read I add to the items.

Comment: Can you insert that part of the code in the question (including the `IsPostBack` condition if there is one)?

Comment: After loading the page the first time, does the list change? If not, you can put the `Page_Load` code inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` conditional block.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks a lot.